# Change the font size of variable names in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am not able to increase the font size of the names of the variables in a graphic realized with ggplot.

I tried to include these codes inside ggplot code, but unsuccessfully :

```
theme(text = element_text(size=20))
theme(axis.text=element_text(size=20))
theme(axis.title=element_text(size=14))
theme_grey(base_size = 20)
geom_text(size=20)
```

My code is :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
dataplot <- read.csv("/Documents/R.csv",header=T,sep=";")
dataPlotMelt <- melt(data = dataplot, id.vars = c("variable"),variable.name = "Method",value.name = "SMD")
varNames <- as.character(dataplot$variable)
dataPlotMelt$variable <- factor(dataPlotMelt$variable,levels = varNames)
ggplot(data=dataPlotMelt,mapping=aes(x=variable,y=SMD,group=Method, color=Method))+
  ylab("Standardizedmeandifference(%)")+
  xlab("") +
  geom_point(aes(shape=Method),size=2) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=15,color="black",size=0.1,linetype="dashed") + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=-15,color="black",size=0.1,linetype="dashed") + 
  coord_flip() + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank()) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(-65,-15,15,105)) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=12)) +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(),legend.key=element_blank()) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("grey","black"))
```

I'd like to increase the font size of the names of the variables in the graphic and, besides, increase the text "Standardized mean difference (%)" and remove the vertical line between the yintercept and ybreak on both sides

[image]

Comment: make sure you use `theme` after `theme_bw`

Answer (score 0):

[new graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwWDF.jpg)
Thank you Richard for giving me the solution. 
As you suggested I used `theme` after `theme_bw`

I managed to suppress the useless vertical lines as well with the command `theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())`

Here is the new code for ggplot :

```
ggplot(data = dataPlotMelt, mapping = aes(x = variable, y = SMD,group = Method, 
  color = Method)) +
  ylab("Standardized mean difference (%)") + xlab("") +
  geom_point(aes(shape = Method),size=2) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 15, color = "black", size = 0.1, linetype = "dashed") + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = -15, color = "black", size = 0.1, linetype = "dashed") +
  coord_flip() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(-65,-15,0,15,105)) +
  theme_bw() + theme(legend.text = element_text(size=13)) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values= c("grey","black")) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=12)) + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size=13)) + 
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) + 
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.key=element_blank())
```